# Prevent cross-domain include in PHP

Tags: php, include, cross-domain

I imagine this question has already been asked but I can't find it, so I am sorry for the eventual duplicate. I have only found the opposite.

How do I prevent cross domain includes in PHP? Is a `preg_match` of the `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]` enough? My guess is no. What is the option, if any, on the **php.ini** to prevent this?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you talking about including PHP scripts?

Comment: Yes, I want to prevent someone from including one of my PHP files on their domain. Maybe it's already set this way, I just want to be sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is already impossible, hence you do not need to worry about it. PHP Source code includes are not processed over `HTTP`. They can be only included if on same server. No one can include your PHP source file in their website by just using its url. Both the scripts have to be on same server

If a PHP source file is included over HTTP, the including party will only see the output generated by the PHP file, not its source code.

In fact, even you yourself cannot `include()` your PHP source file using `HTTP` even if both the files are on same server. Anything that goes through HTTP with a properly working PHP Enabled webserver will not send the source code out to client.

**Example:**

Let's say you have a website example.com and you are on `index.php` and you have to include `sources.php` which resides in the same directory. If you try

```
include("sources.php");  //or "/path/to/your/root/sources.php"
```

This will work as expected and source code will be included. But if you try

```
include("http://www.example.com/sources.php");
```

This will **NOT** include any source code from `sources.php` into your `index.php`, even though you own  both files, they are on same server. This is because when its served via HTTP, the code has already been processed and a properly configured php enabled web server will not send out php source code.

Comment: Thank you, knowing this I can sleep at night instead of deleting public github repositories thinking "what if..."

Comment: Cheers, I just put up an example to illustrate the scenario better, have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

You can't stop people downloading your HTTP resources and using them however they like. (Note they can only include the *output* of your program, not the PHP source code).

You can put barriers in the way (such as checking the user agent string in the HTTP request), but they are easy to bypass.

`php.ini` has no setting to prevent this. It allows you to disable the ability of scripts running on *your* server from including content over HTTP, but not from being included.